# Invalid use of group function how to solve

Tags: mysql

Any ideas I am getting this error when trying to do the following, i am looking for rows which do not have complete values, all the specified values must add up to 98

```
SELECT *
FROM `lesson_tracking`
WHERE
  userID = 19113
  AND sum(dialogue+vocab_1+vocab_2+vocab_3+phrase_1+phrase_2+phrase_3+turorial+culture+dialogue_l+listening+tutorial_ex+writing+lang_ex) != 98
```

Comment: Do you actually want an aggregate SUM() (applied across multiple grouped rows) or do you just want to add the values of those columns _per row_ to be `!= 98`?

Comment: I want the sum of all these values in any row to not be 98

Comment: And now see normalization!

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` is used with group by clause. If you are just adding up column values, you don't need to use `sum()`. in your case. The following is enough

```
SELECT *
FROM `lesson_tracking`
WHERE
  userID = 19113
  AND (dialogue+vocab_1+vocab_2+vocab_3+phrase_1+phrase_2+phrase_3+turorial+culture+dialogue_l+listening+tutorial_ex+writing+lang_ex) != 98
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to remove the SUM function

```
SELECT *
FROM `lesson_tracking`
WHERE
  userID = 19113
  AND dialogue+vocab_1+vocab_2+vocab_3+phrase_1+phrase_2+phrase_3+turorial+culture+dialogue_l+listening+tutorial_ex+writing+lang_ex != 98
```